# Can I ask Acrobat Pro XI to open the PDF document through other applications?

Tags: acrobat

As I need to read help-documentation for Stata, I need to set Acrobat as the default PDF viewer. However, compared to Sumatra, the main drawback is that I can no longer obtain the following menu.

[image]

Is there a way to create such menu-entries in Acrobat, so that I can open other PDF editors from Acrobat? The use-case is: first, have Stata open the help-file correctly in Acrobat; and in Acrobat, with this file under view, open the same file (and show the same page, at best) in an external PDF viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to create such menu-entries in Acrobat, so that I can open other PDF editors from Acrobat?

No. Acrobat does allow menu items to be added via folder level JavaScript but you can't use it to launch other applications in that way. You can cause PDF files to open, but they'd get opened by the default viewer... which is Acrobat... and defeats your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sad though.

Comment: Not sad... secure. You don't want any old PDF to be able to launch applications and start deleting files. Plus, those menu items exist in SumatraPDF because of it's own limitations like filling forms and commenting. Acrobat and the free Reader have these features. Why did you want the user to have the option of multiple PDF viewers?

Comment: Secure for sure, but less user friendly; as you have seen in my customized menu from Sumatra, I do a lot of things with PDFs: `ABBYY` for OCR, `Annotator` for reading PDF on a tablet (with digitizer to write and draw), `PDF-XChange` for reading and marking PDF off a large screen (with keyboard and mouse). When I use Sumatra as my default PDF reader, the workflow is clear: I open and *view* the PDF, and decide what to do with it.

Comment: I was made to set Adobe Acrobat/Reader to be the default PDF viewer simple because Stata (a statistical package) can only have help-files opened correctly through Adobe products. For sure, Adobe Acrobat is secure and strong (in being able to fill up forms etc), but it is not part of my workflow, and does not appear to be able to: the major complaint I have for Adobe Acrobat is that annotation in it takes way too many mouse-clicks. I need to click reach to the mouse and click on the functions to achieve a single action, say, underlining.

Comment: Highlighting seems to be fine: I found a menu-item for it in Acrobat; yet, for underlining, I don't find a menu item, and I should need to move the mouse two times, and click up to 5 times. I can do the same thing (underlining specifically) in `PDF-XChange` within 1 mouse movement, and 1 mouse click. [Or, to be fair, I may just be personally used to using the decade old `PDF-XChange` which I picked up when I enter college :) ]